# Get previous level

Tags: php, function, windows-xp

I got formula to calculate the xp needed for next level

```
function getplayernextlevel($exp) {

$nextlevel = -1;
$level = 0;

while($nextlevel < $exp){
    $nextlevel += pow(($level+1),3)+30*pow(($level+1),2)+30*($level+1)-50;
    $level++;
}
return $nextlevel; }
```

But I can't figure out how can I get the xp needed for previous level, cause I want to calculate the percent of how much percent you need to next level and make progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? It's a quick way to calculate all the bits you need and hand them back as an array instead of a single value:

```
<?php

function getplayernextlevel($exp) {

    $prevlevel = -1;
    $nextlevel = -1;
    $level = 0;

    while($nextlevel < $exp){
        $prevlevel = $nextlevel;
        $nextlevel += pow(($level+1),3)+30*pow(($level+1),2)+30*($level+1)-50;
        $level++;
    }

    return array($level, $prevlevel, $nextlevel); 
}


$sample_result = getplayernextlevel(50);
echo var_dump($sample_result);

echo '<br /> Current Level: ' . $sample_result[0];
echo '<br /> Previous level EXP: ' . $sample_result[1];
echo '<br /> Next level EXP: ' . $sample_result[1];

?>
```